# imported file explanation in Vue CLI (Difference between App vs App.vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Vue Cli**
I don't understand the imported part properly. can anyone please tell me the difference between Vue vs Vue(import Vue from 'vue') as well as App Vs App.vue(import App from App.vue)

import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

new Vue({
el: '#app',
render: h => h(App)
})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Import vue in itself
import Vue from 'vue'

// Import the App component, you can see it as the root of your app that will contain all of your other components
import App from './App.vue'

// Create a new javascript instance of vue
new Vue({
    render: h => h(App), // This new instance will render the app component
}).$mount('#app') // Actually mount the whole application targeting the #app id in the DOM
```